# Line numbers in pseudocode in figures - using lineno in figures

Tags: line-numbering, pseudocode

can someone show an example how to obtain line numbers in the alltt environment **in figures**, possibly using the lineno package?

I've tried:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{alltt}
{\linenumbers
def insert(k, v)
  // ... pseudocode
}
\end{alltt}
\caption{Basic operations I}
\end{figure}
```

but that, or using the `linenumbers` environment, doesn't do anything.
The code above doesn't work even if the `alltt` environment is removed - there are no line numbers if the text is within a figure.

Is there any way to obtain line numbering in figures?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out - one should use the `\internallinenumbers` directive, like this:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{alltt}
{\footnotesize{\internallinenumbers
def insert(k, v)
  // ...
}}
\end{alltt}
\end{figure}
```